# Получить span.html() рядом с radiobutton

Tags: html, jquery

Есть такая верстка с radioкнопками

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="pistons">4<br/>цилиндра</span>
        <b>220 000</b>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" class="with-gap" checked="" value="220 000"/>
        <label for="test1">&nbsp;</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="pistons">6<br/>цилиндров</span>
        <b>280 000</b>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" class="with-gap" value="280 000"/>
        <label for="test2">&nbsp;</label>
    </li>           
    <li>
        <span class="pistons">8<br/>цилиндров</span>
        <b>350 000</b>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test3" class="with-gap" value="350 000"/>
        <label for="test3">&nbsp;</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

При нажатии на кнопку я хочу полчить значение span class="pistons" с выбранной radio кнопкой. Делаю вот так

```
$(".order_lovato").click(function () {
    var $this = $('input[name=group1]:checked');
    var itemBox = '.pistons';
    var $thisItem = $this.closest(itemBox);
    console.log($thisItem.html());
});
```

Но не работает. в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: _Есть такая верстка,_ в которой нет ни одной кнопки. _При нажатии на определенную кнопку_ можно ничего не делать, поскольку нажать на нечто несуществующее невозможно.

Comment: @Qwertiy vacuous truth, эту задачу выполняет любой код, в том числе его полное отсутствие. %)

Comment: @D-side, надо было туда ссылку на [mcve] добавить :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this.siblings('.pistons');
```

попробуйте

Comment: var itemBox = '.pistons';
            var $thisItem = $this.closest(itemBox); разве это не тоже самое?

Comment: вы выбираете все .pistons а .closest() ближайшего подходящего предока. И как он выберет ближайшего предка если все они находятся в переменой? Выборка идет по dom я так понимаю. И потом я не заметил вам же не предок нужен а siblings  я вам на другой вопрос уже ответил как примерно так же $this.siblings(itemBox); надо.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li input').on( 'click', function() {
 $(this).siblings('b').html();
});
```

только потом не забудте к числу привести. Хотя я бы так не организовывал. Действовал через атрибуты. И тег **<b>** по документации [w3c.org deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Способов получить элемент с помощью **jquery** существует множество.

Прочитайте документацию [jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Вам в любом случае надо это знать.

Вот один из них.

Живой пример [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/g809chg6/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#getPriceBtn').click(function() {
    console.log('id', $('input:checked').attr('id'));
    console.log('price', $('input:checked').parent().find('b').text());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>4<br/>цилиндра</span>
        <b>220 000</b>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" class="with-gap" checked/>
        <label for="test1">&nbsp;</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>6<br/>цилиндров</span>
        <b>280 000</b>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" class="with-gap" />
        <label for="test2">&nbsp;</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>8<br/>цилиндров</span>
        <b>350 000</b>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test3" class="with-gap" />
        <label for="test3">&nbsp;</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="getPriceBtn">
      get Price
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".order_lovato").click(function () {
  var thiss = $('input[name=group1]:checked');
  var tmp = thiss.parent().find('.pistons').html();

  console.log(tmp);
});
```

в HTML добавьте

```
<button class="order_lovato">
  dsfgfrfs
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло так

```
var $this = $('input[name=group2]:checked');
var itemBox = '.pistons';
var $thisItem = $this.siblings(itemBox).text();
```